# Are history questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Unix has quite a bit of history, and a lot of things with historical roots.

Should questions primarily about the history of Unix be on topic?

Comment: It depends; [my history question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283219/why-didnt-gnome-3-display-desktop-icons-by-default) was put on hold. I stated in a flag that it is a history question, but still got a simple reply "off-topic".

Answer (score 16):

I think it should be on-topic.

The history of any software can be used to understand why some part of it is the way it is.

Answer (score 6):

I think they're fine as well, and this question made me think of a [history question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/where-did-the-wheel-group-get-its-name) to ask, so hopefully we decide they're on-topic :)

Answer (score 5):

I have no problem per-se so long as they're answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I have been putting some history questions per-se as well. Please see [Can somebody list the earliest public source-code repositories and when they opened?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165582/can-somebody-list-the-earliest-public-source-code-repositories-and-when-they-ope) and if possible open it.