# Should Politics and Idealisms be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/why-does-the-linux-kernel-use-linux-libre-code-to-get-rid-of-binary-blobs) is not the first question, that basically comes down to the answer having something to do with free software idealism. I'm simply wondering if such questions should really be on topic? they technically don't have anything to do with unix. Free Software may have a really strong presence in the Unix community, but it's getting stronger in the windows one too. Should it be ontopic? if so do you think we should have tags like 'gnu' 'floss' 'idealism' 'politics'? Also if it shouldn't should we moderators attempt to retroactively enforce the decision on older posts that were of this nature.

Answer (score 3):

I read [this particular question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/why-does-the-linux-kernel-use-linux-libre-code-to-get-rid-of-binary-blobs) more as a question about Linux, which is on-topic. It's not a technical question, but we seem to have a consensus that [history questions are on-topic](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/are-history-questions-on-topic), and floss¹-related concepts come up often in historical discussions about unix.

I would definitely consider a similar question about a non-unix-related piece of software as off-topic. It's the unix aspect that makes the question on-topic, not the floss aspect (this isn't http://dentistry.stackexchange.com).

Politics and idealism, however, would likely be closed as “subjective and argumentative”.

Answer (score 2):

Although I expect that if these questions are allowed we will most certainly have religious wars, I believe we should first experiment and collect data before we disallow these types of questions.