# have a history tag

Tags: discussion, tags

As I see that historical questions are [on-topic](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/are-history-questions-on-topic) would love to see a tag called `/ history` . Like many of the others, there are lot of historical questions I want to ask and having a history tag would be useful not just for putting my own questions but also to find historical questions I might never have known, thought of or asked.

Looking forward to know what people think of it.

Comment: +1. Sounds like a good idea to me. See also [Are history questions on topic?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73/are-history-questions-on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that exact history tag has already been in existence since 2011-01-01

Comment: @Anthon didn't know that. I also voted to close. Shouldn't it be easier for the person who made the question to close it if the answer is already there. I could delete it as well if that makes any difference but then if somebody has the same query (even mistakenly) would open it again.

Comment: @shirish  IIRC normally you can only delete it if there is no answer yet. If there is an answer, you don't want the OP to be able to invalidate answerers effort by deleting the post (for whatever reason). So voting to close is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Anthon , as muru did take the effort hence voting to close, it seems in meta it takes many more votes to close a question then it does on plain stack sites.

Comment: @shirish It doesn't take more votes, but there are so seldom vote opportunities on meta, that potential voters don't look at the queues that often. That is why it takes so long. There are only 3 queues and on one of them I have not even had a chance to vote.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the name `history`, I suggest using `history-of`, an idea I have seen on [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of). One reason would be to avoid confusion with shell command history.

Oh wait. We already have a [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag with your meaning.